# drawing a slope in random circles python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, graphics

So my program is designed to manipulate certain coordinates in order to create this image:
[image: ![image]

So basically my program draw a bunch of random circles and I have to manipulate the line of equation to create the red sections. So far my image is the following:

[image]
I can't seem to figure out how to add another line equation to create the other red section. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# using the SimpleGraphics library
from SimpleGraphics import *

# tell SimpleGraphics to only draw when I use the update() function
setAutoUpdate(False)


# use the random library to generate random numbers
import random


# size of the circles drawn
diameter = 15

resize(600, 400)


##
# returns a vaid color based on the input coordinates
#
# @param x is an x-coordinate 
# @param y is a y-coordinate 
# @return a colour based on the input x,y values for the given flag
##
def define_colour(x,y):
  ##
  #add your code to this method and change the return value
  slopeOne = (200 - 300)/(0-150)
  b = 0 - (slopeOne * 200)
  slopeTwo = (0-300)/(200 - 800)
  b = 150 - (slopeTwo * 40)



  lineEquationOne = (slopeOne * x) + b
  lineEquationTwo = (slopeTwo * x) + b

  if y > lineEquationOne:
    return "red"
  elif y > lineEquationTwo:
    return "red"
  else:
    return 'white'





######################################################################
#
# Do NOT change anything below this line
#
######################################################################

# repeat until window is closed
while not closed():
  for i in range(500):
    # generate random x and y values 
    x = random.randint(0, getWidth())
    y = random.randint(0, getHeight())

    # set colour for current circle
    setFill( define_colour(x,y) )

    # draw the current circle
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter)

  update()
```

Comment: Where does the SimpleGraphics library come from? How do we get a copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Add back in the commented lines for your second slope and equation and make sure your variable names match up.  Then you just need to add an OR condition for your if statement to set the color based on each equation.

```
# using the SimpleGraphics library
from SimpleGraphics import *

# tell SimpleGraphics to only draw when I use the update() function
setAutoUpdate(False)

# use the random library to generate random numbers
import random

# size of the circles drawn
diameter = 15

resize(600, 400)


##
# returns a valid color based on the input coordinates
#
# @param x is an x-coordinate 
# @param y is a y-coordinate 
# @return a colour based on the input x,y values for the given flag
##
def define_colour(x, y):
    slopeOne = (200 - 300) / (0 - 150)
    b = 0 - (slopeOne * 200)
    slopeTwo = (200 - 300) / (0 - 150)
    b2 = -50 - (slopeTwo * 200)

    lineEquationOne = (slopeOne * x) + b
    lineEquationTwo = (slopeTwo * x) + b2

    if (y > lineEquationOne) | (y < lineEquationTwo):
        return "white"
    else:
        return 'red'


######################################################################
#
# Do NOT change anything below this line
#
######################################################################

# repeat until window is closed
while not closed():
    for i in range(500):
        # generate random x and y values
        x = random.randint(0, getWidth())
        y = random.randint(0, getHeight())

        # set colour for current circle
        setFill(define_colour(x, y))

        # draw the current circle
        ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter)

    update()
```

Comment: So I edited my the comments out but I still don't get the image I want

Comment: @JaneDoe2 I've edited my answer to include a working example - you can modify it by changing the equations to get the image you want.